# Protect WordPress login page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security, authentication

I have a WordPress site. Like with many WordPress sites I see people (probably robots) trying their luck at the login page every once in a while. However, for the past 2 weeks it’s been non-stop at a rate of 400-500 tries a day…
So I went ahead and took the following security measures:

1. Changed the login URL to something different than the regular /wp-admin.
2. Limit the number of login attempts per URL and also automatically block any IP trying to login with an invalid username such as “test” or “admin”.
3. Set up two factor authentication to make sure that even though they tried they would not manage to get in, even if they guessed the username and password.

However that didn’t seem to do much and I’m still seeing a huge number of login attempts, so next thing I did was:

4. Password protect the login URL itself.

And still I’m seeing the same number of login attempts… now my questions are basically 2:

1. How are they managing to still try their luck at the login form even if that page is password protected?
2. Is there anything else I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

[Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) offers a [free entry level plan](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/) that may help reduce some of this traffic before it gets to your site.  Also, their $20/month plan (as of Aug 2017) can be paired with their [WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare/) to use their built-in WordPress rulesets. CloudFlare also has a few more settings to allow you to put a few more filters and road blocks in front of specific types of traffic.

If you do choose to use CloudFlare with WordPress, be sure you understand exactly how/if you are choosing to push content into the CloudFlare CDN (content delivery network) and how that relates to the content cache on your site.

Standard disclaimer: I have no relationship with CloudFlare except as a customer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although that still doesent explain how are they getting to the login form right now

Comment: Maybe you are just seeing 404 errors on /wp-admin/ since you changed it?

Comment: Have you excluded the path to the login page in robots.txt and in the sitemap?